Why does refetchQueries not trigger when errorPolicy is set to 'none' in Apollo Client mutation?
I noticed that the documentation for mutation mentions that the refetchQueries is triggered 'An array (or a function that returns an array) that specifies which queries you want to refetch after the mutation occurs.' The phrase 'mutation occurs' seems to imply that refetchQueries would be triggered regardless of whether the mutation succeeds or fails.
However, based on my code review and testing, when errorPolicy is set to 'none', it interrupts refetchQueries (because an ApolloError is thrown at this point, preventing the subsequent refetchQueries from executing). Is the lack of triggering refetchQueries the expected behavior?
